# how to extract data from excel (apache poi) to put it in mysql table using jsp?

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc, apache-poi

I want to extract data from **excel sheet** to insert it into a **mysql table** using **jsp**, so far i've done this and its printing data into the outpout(**using apache poi**),what should i add to this code ?

**Output :**

```
Name      Age        Adress

Mark       35      New york,AA

Elise      22      India,bb

Charlotte  45      France,cc
```

**Readexcel.jsp** :

```
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>PRINT DATA FROM EXCEL FILE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%

         try{

        boolean ismultipart=ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        if(!ismultipart){


        }else{
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        List items = null;

        try{
          items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
        Iterator itr = items.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            FileItem item = (FileItem)itr.next();
            if(item.isFormField()){

            }else{
                String itemname = item.getName();
                if((itemname==null || itemname.equals(""))){
                    continue;
                }
                String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(itemname);
                File f = checkExist(filename);
                item.write(f);
                try{


        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(item.getInputStream());
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()){
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
            {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                switch (cell.getCellType()){
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "t"); 
                     break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: 
                    out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "t");

                      break;}
            } 
            out.println("");

        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
            }
        }   
    }catch(Exception e){
     }
     finally {
           out.close();
        }

            %>
 <%!
 private File checkExist(String fileName){
    String saveFile = "D:/upload/";
    File f = new File(saveFile+"/"+fileName);

    if(f.exists()){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(fileName);
        sb.insert(sb.lastIndexOf("."),"-"+new Date().getTime());
        f = new File(saveFile+"/"+sb.toString());
    }
    return f;
   }

        %>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I've created a **table** in my database named **EXCELDATA** with the header of the excel sheet :

```
 ExcelData (Name varchar(50),age int,adress varchar(50));
```

what should i add to this code to get the data from the excel sheet to the mysql table ??

Comment: although this works its not the best idea to put code like this in a jsp. You cn google to find out why. A servlet migth be better. also if your wondering why the source html made by this jsp has a lot of blank lines its cause of the <%@page tags on top - nothing wrong if you dont mind them ... if you do just move the end tag to the next line ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my excelimport.jsp file

```
     try{
         String name,age,address=null;

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname","username","password");

        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        PreparedStatement pstm = null ;
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("C://yourexcelfile.xls");
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input ); //creating a new poi reference to the given excel file
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row;
         Statement st=con.createStatement();
        for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){  //points to the starting of excel i.e excel first row
            row = (Row) sheet.getRow(i);  //sheet number

                   if( row.getCell(0)==null) { name = "0";}  //suppose excel cell is empty then its set to 0 the variable
                   else name = row.getCell(0).toString();   //else copies cell data to name variable


                   if( row.getCell(1)==null) { age = "0"; }
                   else age= row.getCell(1).toString();

                   if( row.getCell(2)==null) { address = "0";   }
                   else  address   = row.getCell(2).toString();






     String sq="INSERT INTO ExcelData(name,age,address) VALUES('"+name+"','"+age+"','"+address+"')";                   

            pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sq);//here we are using prepared statement because we are calling this statement for each row
            pstm.execute();
            System.out.println("Import rows "+i);
        }
        con.commit();
        pstm.close();
        con.close();
        input.close();
        System.out.println("Success import excel to mysql table");

    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        out.println(e);
    }catch(SQLException ex){
       out.println(ex);
    }catch(IOException ioe){
       out.println(ioe);
    }


%>
```

Comment: Hi dileep , i tried your code after modifying it and this message shows up in my jsp : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver , ichecked my mysql database and the "ExcelData table " is empty ,what should i do

Comment: add MySQL jdbc driver jar file in to your libraries...folder and please find jar file in below url https://code.google.com/p/find-ur-pal/downloads/detail?name=mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar&  and let me know....

Comment: it's already done , i added apache poi jars +mysql-connector,but still no data in my table